# Format list elements in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my viewmodel I have `SubscriptionExpires` formatted as below

```
    public class IndexViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dddd d MMMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? SubscriptionExpires { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

`Device` also includes a date property

```
    public partial class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public DateTime UnlockedTo { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way of setting the date format for `UnlockedTo` in `IndexViewModel` or must formatting for this property be done in the view?

Answer (score 1):

View should be responsible for formatting and showing data. Model is responsible just to deliver those data.

Comment: Thank you @dawidr but I wasn't referring to the model. I was referring to the viewmodel. Data Annotations allow formatting in the viewmodel and I am using Data Annotations to format  `IndexViewModel.SubscriptionExpires`. The question is whether or not it is possible to format `IndexViewModel.Devices.UnlockedTo` in the viewmodel. Whether or not one should is another question.